# Select data from single column as multiple record

Tags: mysql

I have the following table structure in a mysql database.

```
id |     files          | status
 1    a.pdf,b.pdf,c.pdx   1   
 2    d.pdf,e.pdf.g.pdf   2    
 3    x.pdf,k.pdf,y.pdf   1
```

As you can see, the attachments are all stored on a single line.
My query is supposed to select all rows where status = 1  so i'm expecting the data in the following format.

```
1    1   a.pdf     1   
2    1   b.pdf     1   
3    1   c.pdf     1   
4    3   x.pdf     1    
5    3   k.pdf     1   
6    3   y.pdf     1
```

Unfortunately, I am unsure which operator I can use to accomplish this. I'm aware SQL has pivot but i doubt even that can address my issue.

As a result, I would appreciate if I could get any help in the condition of the select query.

Regards

Comment: What do 1 through 6 represent?

Comment: You're really starting from the wrong place. First, normalise your schema.

Comment: 1-6 is just row IDs.

Comment: @Strawberry I cant change this, the best thing would be all attachments stored in a different table, but its in the row and i'm trying to retrieve it. I cant change the structure

Comment: @Niana which mysql version you are using?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consider the following...

I have a table (ints) of integers (0-9)...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,files VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
,status INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'a.pdf,b.pdf,c.pdx',1),
(2,'d.pdf,e.pdf,g.pdf',2),
(3,'x.pdf,k.pdf,y.pdf',1);


SELECT DISTINCT id
              , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(files,',',i2.i*10+i1.i+1),',',-1) file
              , status
           FROM my_table
              , ints i1
              , ints i2
          WHERE status = 1
          ORDER
             BY id, i2.i*10+i1.i;
   +----+-------+--------+
   | id | file  | status |
   +----+-------+--------+
   |  1 | a.pdf |      1 |
   |  1 | b.pdf |      1 |
   |  1 | c.pdx |      1 |
   |  3 | x.pdf |      1 |
   |  3 | k.pdf |      1 |
   |  3 | y.pdf |      1 |
   +----+-------+--------+
```

Comment: Oh.. Now I see the difference. Your example works fine as you have `DISTINCT`. I was not attentive enough, sorry. But if it would be a needed. for example, to add an index of file this won't work.

Comment: @Strawberry Thank you for your answer. I am trying to understand.I see that i from the ints table is used to increment.  So I can easily create that table if it's needed. If I have to hard code the values from 0-9, are there limitations? say I have 1000 results seperated by a comma?

Comment: @Strawberry I'm having a little trouble understanding which part is hardcode so I can modify it. Noting that the example data was just an example as i anticipate more rows.
Server version: 10.4.11-MariaDB

Comment: @Strawberry Doesnt seem to work 100%, I am only getting 1 pdf name, not the other 2

Comment: @Strawberry if I use `SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(file,',',i2.i*10+i1.i+1),',',-1) file` the rows are returned with only the first file. 
However if I use
`SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(file, ',', i1.i), ',', -1) file,` all the files are returned, however I think your version is supposed to account for more file listings

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216583/discussion-between-niana-and-strawberry).

Comment: `SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(file, ',', i1.i), ',', -1) file,` would not work for the large number of commas?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SET @row_num = 0;
SELECT
    (@row_num := @row_num + 1) ROW_NUM,
    id,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(files, ',', idx), ',', -1) FileName,
    status
FROM
    test
JOIN 
    (SELECT 1 idx UNION ALL SELECT 2 idx UNION ALL SELECT 3 idx UNION ALL SELECT 4 idx UNION ALL SELECT 5 idx) idxs
    on idxs.idx - 2 < LENGTH(files) - LENGTH(REPLACE(files, ",", ""))
WHERE status = 1
;
```

Just add as many indexes as your max count of files in a string.

Note that there should be no comma fater last filename. This is magic `-2` is responsible for.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, i'm trying to understand this, can you tell me why where is a select 1, then select 2 up to 5?

Comment: In `WHERE` clause the status filter is applied. If you are asking about nested table with unions, this is just a way to have indexes from 1 to 5. If you need more, just add more `UNION LL SELECT x inx`.

Comment: So i have to keep adding Union ALL SELECT 6 X INX , then 7, 8, 9 etc?

Comment: If you need more than 5, yes. But you can use index table instead if you want to. This is an example on how to generate indexes without table. You can use cartesian of several (select 0... 9) unions. 2 will produce indexes from 0 to 99

Comment: I joined with two indexes tables, how would the stringstring_index line change?

Comment: How have you joined then? Why would `stringstring_index` change? If you cross joined two sets of union from 0 to 9 then just calculate the index you need as `idx1*10 + idx2` that would give you indexes from 0 to 99